# How to call a function from a different function?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a simple app that counts the characters of a textfield, but when the user inputs the text, the function that converts the user-inputed string into a var and the function that counts the characters are executed at once. Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myTextField : UITextField
    @IBOutlet var userTextField : UITextField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        myTextField.text = fullConstant
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func modifyMyVariable(sender : AnyObject) {
        myVariable = userTextField.text
    }
    @IBAction func clickMe(sender : AnyObject) {
        countCharacters(&fullConstant)
        println(fullConstant)
        myTextField.text = fullConstant
    }
}
```

And here's the "OtherFile.swift" where the functions are located:

```
import Foundation

var fullConstant = "Type something!"
var myVariable = ""

func modifyMyVariable() {
    println()
}

func countCharacters(inout fullConstant: String) {
    let FirstPart = "There are "
    let LastPart = " characters"
    var numberOfCharacters = countElements(myVariable)
    switch numberOfCharacters {
    case 0 :
        fullConstant = "There isn't any character yet"
    case 1 :
        fullConstant = "There is just one character"
    default :
        fullConstant = FirstPart + String(numberOfCharacters) + LastPart
    }
}
```

Both functions execute as soon the userTextField is edited, but if the user inputs one character, the `countCharacters` function takes the var `myVariable` before it's modified by the function `modifyMyvariable`, so it doesn't count the last character added.

To solve this, I've thought that I could call the function `countCharacters` from the function `modifyMyVariable`, so the variable `myVariable` has already changed when it counts the characters.

Comment: "I've thought that I could call the function countCharacters from the function modifyMyVariable" And what happens when you try?

Comment: What events are hooked to your IBActions?

Comment: Nothing, that's why I suppose I'm not calling the function properly. Both IBActions are triggered with the "Editing changed" on the userTextField.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following and see if it's then easier to fix your problem.

- You should always only link each event to one IBAction. Your IBActions shouldn't be named after what you're trying to do in them; they should be named after the event that triggers them. For example, "modifyMyVariable" should be called "textEdited" or similar.
- In that "textEdited" method, do all the work you need to do. If you need to call another function, call it from there instead of linking to two IBActions.
- Put code in your "OtherFile" inside a

  ```
  class OtherFile {
  }
  ```

block, and hold an instance to that class as a variable in your view controller. You want to avoid declaring global functions outside of classes.

- Not related, but name your constants using camelCase with first letter lower case, just like your variables. So FirstPart should be firstPart.
- Avoid using 'inout' as much as possible. Each language has it's conventions; in ObjC and Swift, pass in values needed to do work, and return values that result from that work. So:

  ```
  func countCharacters(text: String) -> (String)
  ```

  - Putting it all together, your 'modifyMyVariable' function (which should really be called 'textEdited') will look something like this:

    ```
    myVariable = userTextField.text
    let characterCount = self.myOtherFileInstance.countCharacters(myVariable)
    myTextField.text = characterCount
    ```

and the other function (clickMe) should be deleted.